# Implementing keyword "const"

Tags: c

A constant pointer is a pointer which points to a fixed memory location throughout.The question is how do you ensure that this behavior is ensured without using the keyword constant while declaring the pointer in a C program.

Comment: How do you eat without chewing? You eat by chewing, and you get `const` behavior by using the `const` keyword. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Winston:According to you such a thing is not possible is it?

Comment: The question actually make sense, I think. I believe the OP wants to know the internals of `const` keyword by trying to create a constant without using the keyword itself, but the phrasing could indeed be improved.

Comment: @MainMa: Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish something in C? Or are you just wanting to understand how const works?

Comment: Frankly I want to accomplish that in C if possible.

Comment: why? Why can't you just use const?

Comment: For the most part, `const` is not "implemented" really.  It's a message for the compiler telling it to generate an error if it sees an attempt to modify the variable tagged `const`.  As such, trying to "accomplish" it in C without the keyword really doesn't make sense.  Even with the keyword, you can often modify `const` values using pointer/casting tricks.  (There is the caveat that optimizers may do things differently with things labeled `const`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, `const` isn't "implemented".  It's a message to the compiler about whether to generate errors.  `gcc` compiles this:

```
const char *cp = "Hello";
```

to

```
.section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
```

L_.str:                                 ## @.str
    .asciz   "Hello"

```
.section    __DATA,__data
.globl  _cp                     ## @cp
.align  3
```

and this:

```
char *cp = "Hello";
```

to the exact same this:

```
.section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
```

L_.str:                                 ## @.str
    .asciz   "Hello"

```
.section    __DATA,__data
.globl  _cp                     ## @cp
.align  3
```

Comment: Isn't their anyway by which we can ensure this property by using some structure or something?

Comment: @user3762579, no, not really. Note that C originally didn't have the const keyword, and there was no magic way "using structures" or something to get the same effect. You could use the preprocessor to define compile time constants like "#define PI 3.14159" or "#define BEGIN_VIDEO_MEMORY 0xC0000000", but it wasn't the same thing as being able to declare something const.